# How can I populate the Azure AD login page with an email address of my choice?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I've got an MVC 5 app that first logs in business users with their SQL Standard credentials, and then redirects them to the Azure AD login page. (We can't use any sort of SSO solution. The tool that the app exposes makes extensive use of SQL logins. We need the Azure AD to do MFA with the Microsoft Authenticator app. This isn't a publicly available application, it's for known vetted users only).

What I'd really like to do is **populate the email address field on that login page** with the email address we've got stored for the user in our database. I've looked around quite a bit and this doesn't seem easily possible. Any ideas? What am I missing?

Answer (score 7):

In the sign in request, you can append `&login_hint=username@company.com`

The documentation for this is here: (CTRL+F login_hint) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#send-the-sign-in-request